# Tensorflow is unable to run code on too many GPUs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I have the following test code:

```
    import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def body(x):
    a = tf.random_uniform(shape=[2, 2], dtype=tf.int32, maxval=100)
    b = tf.constant(np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]]), dtype=tf.int32)
    c = a + b
    return tf.nn.relu(x + c)

def condition(x):
    return tf.reduce_sum(x) < 100

x = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0, shape=[2, 2]))

with tf.Session():
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
    result = tf.while_loop(condition, body, [x])
    print(result.eval())
```

when I run it on my GPU cluster, I produce the following error:

```
2018-03-30 18:10:33.473913: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1041] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 10415 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:3d:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-03-30 18:10:33.591203: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1041] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 with 10415 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 1, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:3e:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-03-30 18:10:33.688390: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1041] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:2 with 10415 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 2, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:60:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-03-30 18:10:33.806845: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1041] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:3 with 10415 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 3, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:61:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-03-30 18:10:33.913200: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1041] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:4 with 10415 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 4, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:b1:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-03-30 18:10:34.018533: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1041] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:5 with 10415 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 5, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:b2:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
Killed
```

When I run the script using `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES='6' python script.py` it aborts using the GPU. What could be causing this? Could this be a defective GPU?

`nvidia-smi` reports the following:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.25                 Driver Version: 390.25                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:3D:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 28%   21C    P8     8W / 250W |      0MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:3E:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 28%   21C    P8     7W / 250W |      0MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:60:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 28%   24C    P8     8W / 250W |      0MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:61:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 28%   25C    P8     8W / 250W |      0MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   4  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:B1:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 28%   19C    P8     8W / 250W |      0MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   5  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:B2:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 28%   20C    P8     8W / 250W |      0MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   6  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:DA:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 28%   22C    P8     8W / 250W |      0MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   7  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:DB:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 28%   21C    P8     8W / 250W |      0MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Tensorflow version is `1.7.0` and CUDA version is `9.0.176`

Comment: Your code did not produce any error in my environment.

Comment: Hence, this is a problem with the device?

Comment: Can you tell CUDA version and Tensorflow version ?

Comment: And run `nvidia-smi` and show the output

Comment: If I worked with a lower TF version, would that work?

Comment: I think you have to use with  `tf.device('/gpu:0'):` to play with multiple GPUs. See this [link](https://gist.github.com/j-min/69aae99be6f6acfadf2073817c2f61b0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't request enough RAM space when creating a job to use that many GPUs. To use 8 GPUs, you need a good amount of space, perhaps ~60 Gi.